# Enable oauth login with django-allauth but a custom provider

Tags: python, django, oauth, django-allauth, oauth-provider

I have built an oauth provider using [django-oauth-toolkit](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit).

I would now like to allow users of my client application to log in through this provider.

My understanding is that [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) is the ideal tool for this.

I see that django-allauth has a special folder for each provider, and in this folder there is a special files called `provider.py`. For example, [this](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/allauth/socialaccount/providers/github) is the folder for the github provider.

Should I be creating something similar to this folder, specially for my custom provider ? Or is there an easier/better way to do this ?

Comment: Hello there! I just getting start a new project and having similar problem that I want to use django-oauth-toolkit for provider and django-allauth for consumer. Have you found any tutorial or document regarding this?

Comment: No unfortunately :(

Comment: Thank for replying anyway.

Comment: @Brachamul Did you find the solution for Django OAuth client?

Comment: https://github.com/raphaelyancey/django-oauth2-example

Answer (score 10):

This is a interesting article that explains this topic:

- https://raphaelyancey.fr/en/2018/05/28/setting-up-django-oauth2-server-client.html

Answer (score 9):

Based on what the documentation says, it discovers new providers based on `INSTALLED_APPS`. So you will need a Django app that has the same structure yes and includes a `providers.py`. So you should be able to use a new app or an existing one.

This is from the [docs](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#customizing-providers):

> When an existing provider doesn’t quite meet your needs, you might
>   find yourself needing to customize a provider.
>
> This can be achieved by subclassing an existing provider and making
>   your changes there. Providers are defined as django applications, so
>   typically customizing one will mean creating a django application in
>   your project, containing your customized urls.py, views.py and
>   provider.py files. What behaviour you can customize is beyond the
>   scope of this documentation.

Also, a note about the contents of the `providers.py` file:

> In your provider.py file, you will need to expose the provider class
>   by having a module level attribute called provider_classes with your
>   custom classes in a list. This allows your custom provider to be
>   registered properly on the basis of the INSTALLED_APPS setting.